# Dynamic Thresholds in a PromQL query

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have the following defined

```
    - record: node_load5:node_cpu_seconds_total:critical
      expr: 3

    - record: node_load5:node_cpu_seconds_total:critical
      expr: 5
      labels:
        app: loki

    - record: Node_High_LoadAverage:Query
      expr: ((node_load5 / count without (cpu, mode) (node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="system"})))
```

and want to use a query in an Prometheus alert that evaulates the threshold by the value specified by the label or a default value.

I can evaluate the `node_load5:node_cpu_seconds_total:critical` to two different values and use `Node_High_LoadAverage:Query` to abbreviate a query.

I'm trying to use `group_left` and `on` to perform a join.  This is my query that isn't working.

```
Node_High_LoadAverage:Query > on (app) group_left node_load5:node_cpu_seconds_total:critical
```

Has anybody done something similar and is willing to share their working example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
something > on (team) group_left something_too_high_threshold
```

This uses a “join” operator based on the “team” label to apply the different metric and threshold values.  In this example, the “team” label must exist on the “something” metrics as well as the different “something_too_high_threshold” expressions.

Here is the rules mock up of this.

```
    - record: something
      expr: 600
    - record: something
      expr: 400
      labels:
        team: elsewhere
    - record: something
      expr: 300
      labels:
        team: foo
    - record: something
      expr: 500
      labels:
        team: bar
    - record: something_too_high_threshold
      expr: 200
      labels:
        team: foo
    - record: something_too_high_threshold
      expr: 400
      labels:
        team: bar
```

This can be improved by handling metrics where the label doesn't exist.

```
something > on (team) group_left() ( something_too_high_threshold or on (team) something * 0 + 100 )
```

This uses the same mock up rules above and provides default values “something” metrics that either don’t include the label or is not defined in the something_too_high_threshold

This web page, https://www.robustperception.io/using-time-series-as-alert-thresholds,  helped me figure this out.